# How to resolve dagger error - String cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Hi I have a PdfTicketStorage class which has a constructor which accepts 2 parameters, I have added @Inject to the constructor and also it in the MockServiceOrderModule. but I get an error

`MockAppComponent.java:48: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.`

full error is

```
/home/circleci/code/app/src/androidTest/java/com/xx/xxx/test/injection/components/MockAppComponent.java:48: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public interface MockAppComponent extends AppComponent {
       ^
      java.lang.String is injected at
          com.xxx.xx.test.injection.modules.MockServiceOrderModule.providePdfTicketStorage(cloudStorageBucket, …)
      com.xxx.xx.printing.storage.PdfTicketStorage is injected at
          com.xxx.xx.clean.offline.OfflineHelper(…, pdfTicketStorage, …)
      com.xxx.xx.clean.offline.OfflineHelper is injected at
          com.xxx.xx.clean.offline.repository.OfflineUserApiRepository(…, offlineHelper)
      com.xxx.xx.clean.offline.repository.OfflineUserApiRepository is injected at
          com.xxx.xx.clean.florder.data.repository.flOrderRepository(offlineUserApiRepository, …)
      com.xxx.xx.clean.florder.data.repository.flOrderRepository is injected at
          com.xxx.xx.test.scenarios.BaseScenario.flOrderRepository
      com.xxx.xx.test.scenarios.BaseScenario is injected at
          com.xxx.xx.test.injection.components.MockAppComponent.inject(com.xxx.xx.test.scenarios.BaseScenario)
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      com.xxx.xx.test.injection.components.MockAppComponent.inject(com.xxx.xx.test.scenarios.VehicleTakeoverScenario)
      com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent.inject(com.xxx.xx.activities.MainActivity) [com.xxx.xx.test.injection.components.MockAppComponent → com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent]
      com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent.inject(com.xxx.xx.fragments.fller.florder.BaseflOrderFragment) [com.xxx.xx.test.injection.components.MockAppComponent → com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent]
      com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent.inject(com.xxx.xx.fragments.fller.florder.BaseflOrderDataFragment) [com.xxx.xx.test.injection.components.MockAppComponent → com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent]
      com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent.inject(com.xxx.xx.fragments.fller.florder.flOrderDataFragment) [com.xxx.xx.test.injection.components.MockAppComponent → com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent]
      com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent.inject(com.xxx.xx.fragments.fller.florder.flOrderSummaryFragment) [com.xxx.xx.test.injection.components.MockAppComponent → com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent]
      com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent.inject(com.xxx.xx.fragments.fller.florder.flOrderDeallocationFragment) [com.xxx.xx.test.injection.components.MockAppComponent → com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent]
      com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent.inject(com.xxx.xx.clean.orderslist.serviceorders.view.ServiceOrderListFragment) [com.xxx.xx.test.injection.components.MockAppComponent → com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent]
      com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent.inject(com.xxx.xx.fragments.fller.florder.ServiceOrderViewFragment) [com.xxx.xx.test.injection.components.MockAppComponent → com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent]
      com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent.inject(com.xxx.xx.clean.orderslist.serviceorders.view.ServiceOrderAdapter) [com.xxx.xx.test.injection.components.MockAppComponent → com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent]
      and 31 others/home/circleci/code/app/src/androidTest/java/com/xx/xxx/test/injection/components/MockAppComponent.java:48: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.lang.String cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
```

PdfTicketStorage

```
@PerApp
public class PdfTicketStorage {

    private final String cloudStorageBucket;
    private final Lazy<OfflineHelper> offlineHelper;

    @Inject
    public PdfTicketStorage(String cloudStorageBucket, Lazy<OfflineHelper> offlineHelper) {
        this.cloudStorageBucket = cloudStorageBucket;
        this.offlineHelper = offlineHelper;
    }
}
```

OfflineHelper

```
@PerApp
class OfflineHelper @Inject constructor(
    private val app: App,
    private val settings: Settings,
    private val pdfTicketStorage: PdfTicketStorage,
    @Named("default") private val gson: Gson
)
```

MockServiceOrderModule

```
@Module
public class MockServiceOrderModule {

      @Provides @PerApp
    PdfTicketStorage providePdfTicketStorage(String cloudStorageBucket, Lazy<OfflineHelper> offlineHelper) {
        return new PdfTicketStorage(cloudStorageBucket, offlineHelper);
    }

}
```

Could you suggest what am I doing wrong here please

your suggestions on how can I resolve this please
this would be very helpful

thanks
R

Comment: Seems like you're injecting a string somewhere in `MockServiceOrderModule`. Either provide the string in a module or avoid injecting it.

Comment: hello wehen you say avoid injecting it? what did you mean by that, remove Inject from ` @Inject
    public PdfTicketStorage(String cloudStorageBucket, Lazy<OfflineHelper> offlineHelper) {
        this.cloudStorageBucket = cloudStorageBucket;
        this.offlineHelper = offlineHelper;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Dagger's acyclic graph does not know how to provide the type `String`, in the case of `String cloudStorageBucket`. There are two solutions:

1. Either create another `@Provides` for `String`. This is not recommended as you'll run into issue if another `String` type is required.
2. (Recommended) Mark the `@Provides` in the 1 with `@Named("cloudStorageBucket")`.

You can also use `@assisted-inject` if this `String` will be provided at runtime.

Comment: Hello @Karan did you mean this from the 2nd recommended option, ```  @Provides @PerApp
    PdfTicketStorage providePdfTicketStorage(@Named("default") String cloudStorageBucket, Lazy<OfflineHelper> offlineHelper) {
        return new PdfTicketStorage(cloudStorageBucket, offlineHelper);
    }```

Comment: What's happening right now is you are asking dagger to give you an instance of String from its graph. If you have a provides that return a string than dagger will return that. But the reason why its a good idea to Named this string is because in the future you might need to provide more String dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, When you are already providing the object here in this dagger module:

```
@Module
public class MockServiceOrderModule {

      @Provides @PerApp
    PdfTicketStorage providePdfTicketStorage(String cloudStorageBucket, Lazy<OfflineHelper> offlineHelper) {
        return new PdfTicketStorage(cloudStorageBucket, offlineHelper);
    }

}
```

You don't need to use constructor injection in `PdfTicketStorage` class. You can just inject the object and use then like this:

```
@PerApp
public class PdfTicketStorage {

    @Inject
    public PdfTicketStorage pdfTicketStorage;
}
```

But also you have to make sure to provides the string in dagger module also. Not sure why you need to provide the string in dagger module?